# FBA + Ldap Authentication: Email as the username

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, ldap

I have a web application configured with FBA and LDAP. It working as expected and users are able to login but they have to use their username not email address. What changes do I need to make to allow users to login using their email addresses? Following is the membership config:

```
<add name="LdapMember" 
        type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
        server="xxxx.xxxx.com" 
        port="389" useSSL="false" 
        userDNAttribute="distinguishedName" 
        userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName" 
        userContainer="dc=xxxx,dc=com" 
        userObjectClass="person" 
        userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)" 
        scope="Subtree" 
        otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn" />
```

I have tried adding the attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName" and confirmed userPrincipalName is where we store email addresses. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here in case somebody is looking for the answer to this:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/de054a41-0e97-4e8f-912a-0fb799a5587a/?prof=required